# Can't render output to screen using PHP?

Tags: php

I have the following scenario.

I have a PHP website witch contains about 3 webpages with dynamic content. I want to render this to static content to another file. Eg. contact.php -> contact.html

My code looks like this

```
ob_start();
$content = require_once 'contact.php';
ob_end_flush();
file_put_contents("contact.html", $content);
```

Somehow this is not working ;-?(

Comment: Why not have the browser simply try to load `contact.php` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

require_once() doesn't return the content outputted by a script. You need to get the script output that is stored in the output buffer:

```
ob_start();
require_once('contact.php');
$content = ob_get_clean();

file_put_contents('contact.html', $content);
```

**ob_get_clean()**:

> Gets the current buffer contents and
>   delete current output buffer.
>
> ob_get_clean() essentially executes
>   both ob_get_contents() and
>   ob_end_clean().

http://php.net/ob_get_clean

Answer (score 2):

```
ob_start();
require_once('contact.php');
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
file_put_contents("contact.html", $content);
```

Answer (score 2):

`require_once` opens the file and tries to parse it as PHP. It won't return its output. What you're probably looking for is this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once('file.php');
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();
// etc...
?>
```

This way, the script both stores the data in $content AND dumps them to standard output. If you only wanted $content to be populated, use `ob_end_clean()` instead of `ob_end_flush()`.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout ob_get_flush( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-flush.php )

Basically try to do

```
if(!is_file("contact.html")){
  ob_start();
  require_once 'contact.php';
  $content = ob_get_flush();
  file_put_contents("contact.html", $content);
}else{
  echo file_gut_contents("contact.html");
}
```

This should buffer the the output from `contact.php` and dump it when needed.